# Windows update causes IIS Express to fail with ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: windows, iis, windows-10, http2, iis-express

I've been building reactjs apps on a windows machine for the past year, running the Visual Studio IIS test server for debugging / testing.

I just installed a [windows update pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-25-2021-kb5003254-cumulative-update-preview-for-net-framework-3-5-and-4-8-for-windows-10-version-2004-windows-server-version-2004-windows-10-version-20h2-windows-server-version-20h2-and-windows-10-version-21h1-69caa82d-225c-4833-b5ab-8b6c7cacd02d), rebooted, and my local VS IIS Express server fails to serve my sites anymore-- the only errors reported are:

```
localhost/:19 GET https://localhost:44332/static/js/main.chunk.js net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
localhost/:19 GET https://localhost:44332/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
```

I have no idea where to start debugging this-- this `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` seems to have a bunch of possible causes. Rebooting, clearing my browser caches, using incognito mode, using other browsers all seem to have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching I came across this SO thread, which was the solution for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747270/reactjs-neterr-http2-protocol-error-200-with-netcore-in-https/67767129#67767129